# React AntDesign Form validation on all input fields across all table pages

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form with a table consisting of some input fields. After 5 rows are created, the next row will be shown on the next page of the table pagination. The problem is if I do form validation, only the input fields on the active table page are checked. All the other inputs on other pages are not checked. For example, if I have 5 filled input fields on page 1 (active) and 2 empty input fields on page 2, the validation will succeed even if there are empty inputs on other pages. Any idea to go around this problem is appreciated.

Link to codesandbox (add items more than 5 times -> generate): https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-dew-xxx5f?file=/src/form.js

Comment: Would simply recommend to do that you can ONLY go to another page (via pagination) when the form, that is currently opened page, is valid. And put the actual submit button, to submit the entire form, on last page of pagination. That way users will NOT be allowed to go to another page and will be forced to fill in the pages in a row. This is also one of the good practises to do with user interactions in forms - never allow the user to switch the page without filling all the form data in the current one. And if you require, you can save per page data in state just in case (for end submit)

Comment: @Lith "And if you require, you can save per page data in state just in case (for end submit)" I'm interested in this second option. How do I validate manually using the state as the input and not the form input fields? I think Ant Design FormInstance doesn't have methods that validate from a state, just the rendered form input fields..

Comment: Sorry for late response. You can save data into a state per page when the page is validated. Basically the logic would be that each page is a new form and pagination, that switches pages, submits a form. If antd validates it - the data stores into a store and you go to the other page. This way its good practise + the data is being validated by antd